# Select one of two wpf implementations with a bool variable

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application I want to switch between editing and just displaying data in my view.
In order to edit them I have textboxes. For Displaying I am using textblock.
Some of the Data is displayed inside a ListView.

In my ViewModel I have variables called "IsEditingMode" and "IsNotEditingMode" to determine the state of the view.

Now I want something like this in wpf:

```
    <switch betwen implementation>
       <use textbox if IsEditingMode>
       <use textblock if IsNotEditingMode>
```

I tried this using Converters to change the Visibility of the textbox and the textblock:

Converter:

```cs
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var boolValue = (bool)value;

        if (boolValue)
            return Visibility.Visible;

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Provide the Converter a Resource:
`<helper:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IsVisibleConverter"/>`

Use the converter to change the Visibility of the elements in my xaml:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text ="{Binding TextVariableInVM}" Visibility="{Binding    IsNotEditingMode, Converter={StaticResource IsVisibleConverter}}"/>

        <TextBox Text ="{Binding TextVariableInVM}" 
                         Visibility="{Binding IsEditingMode, 
                         Converter={StaticResource IsVisibleConverter}}"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

The result is:

- Editing mode: The Textbox is displayed
- Not editing mode: The TextBlock is displayed

For a small number of displayed variables this is just fine.
In my real application I have a huge amount of displayed variables and some of them are displayed using listview.
In that case my UI is getting really slow.

I believe that this is due to the fact that I bind each variable twice.

Is there a more elegant solution to do that editing <-> not editing switch?

Comment: Can't you just set the TextBox properties IsReadOnly to true and BorderThickness to 0 (or BorderBrush to null) when editing is disabled?

Comment: Yes, that would do the trick. Thank you. But still, I want to know if there is another solution. I have to use Converters for your solution and fear the performance drawbacks.

Comment: You don't have to use Converters, just a DataTrigger in a TextBox Style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use only a `TextBox` element for both situations?
`TextBox` has a property called `IsReadOnly` that you can set to **true** or **false** depending on your action.

Is this code enough for your need's?
It's a `TextBox` that binds your text, and changes from edit mode or not.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextVariableInVM}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsNotEditingMode}"/>
```

If you complain about UI being slow, this example will be faster and more elegant because:

- Doesn't need a `StackPanel`
- One text element instead of two
- Just one extra property needed to check if is editable or not
- Doesn't need to convert from `Boolean` to `Visibility`

---

You may also want to remove the TextBox Border when it is read-only by a Style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```